# How to use INSERT...SELECT to insert data form one table to another based on form input

Tags: php, mysql

I have situation when i want to add data from column formCompany, formPlace in tabel1 based on input from form into table2 column formCompany, formPlace. Something like this:

```
$formCompany = $_POST['formCompany'];

$formPlace = $_POST['formPlace'];

$formOffer = $_POST['formOffer'];


$sql="INSERT INTO table2  (formCompany, formPlace, formOffer) values ("SELECT table1.formCompany, table1.formPlace from table1 where formCompany LIKE '%$formCompany%' AND formPlace LIKE '%$formPlace%'", '$formOffer')"
```

Comment: don't you forget to escape your values?

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), passing the values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. The site you save may just be your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off

**Fix the SQL injection hole**
Use PDO, or

```
$formCompany = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formCompany']);
$formPlace = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formPlace']);
$formOffer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formOffer']);
```

**The syntax for insert select does not include the keyword 'VALUES'**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table2  
      (formCompany, formPlace, formOffer) 
      SELECT table1.formCompany, table1.formPlace, '$formOffer' "
        //All insertions happen here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      ." FROM table1 
        WHERE formCompany LIKE '%$formCompany%' 
          AND formPlace LIKE '%$formPlace%' ";
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. The syntax is ok and the code is also ok. That's save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (fromCompany, fromPlace, fromOffer) SELECT table1.fromCompany, table1.fromPlace, '$fromOffer' AS t1fromOffer FROM table1 WHERE table1.formCompany LIKE '%$formCompany%' AND table1.formPlace LIKE '%$formPlace%'
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. This code and syntax is very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlSelect="SELECT table1.formCompany, table1.formPlace from table1 where formCompany LIKE '%$formCompany%' AND formPlace LIKE '%$formPlace%'";
```

fetch it and use it in your INSERT query

or

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table2  (formCompany, formPlace, formOffer) SELECT table1.formCompany, table1.formPlace, '$formOffer' from table1 where formCompany LIKE '%$formCompany%' AND formPlace LIKE '%$formPlace%'"
```